# Defining section and label in one macro

Tags: sectioning, labels

I want to define a section (or whatever) and label it at the same time. So far I get this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref,cleveref}

    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\mySection}[1]{%
        \cleardoublepage%
        \section{#1}%
        \@bsphack\begingroup%
        \def\@currentlabel{#1}%
        \label{#1}%
        
        \endgroup\@esphack
        %\protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {#1}{{#1}{}}}%
        }
    \makeatother

\begin{document}

  \mySection{Intro duction}

  ref: \ref{Intro duction} foo\\
  nameref: \nameref{Intro duction} bar\\
  cref: \cref{Intro duction} foo\\
  cref*: \cref*{Intro duction} bar\\
  Cref: \Cref{Intro duction} foo\\
  Cref*: \Cref*{Intro duction} bar\\

\end{document}
```

I get:

ref: Intro duction foo
nameref: Intro duction bar
cref: section 1 foo
cref*: section 1 bar
Cref: Section 1 foo
Cref*: Section 1 bar

I think the problem is the `\def\@currentlabel` part. Can some one provide a answer?

Comment: simply `\section{#1}\label{#1}` should be quite enough. But personally I think it is a bad idea to build the label from the section title. A title can contain commands which shouldn't be in a label key. And if you change or reword the title you will have to adapt all the references.

Comment: What's the advantage in having `\ref{Intro duction}` to print “Intro duction”? Your definition does exactly this.

Comment: I do this for one specific document where the guidelines are such as. I just want to stay in continuity and have one specific command to change if I need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made things much more complicated than they need to be. You can simplify the definition to:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\mySection}{+m}{
    \cleardoublepage
    \section{#1}
    \label{#1}
    }
```

(You should develop the habit of preferring `\NewDocumentCommand` over `\newcommand`). You could modify the command a bit further to allow specifying an optional argument after the section title to override the label name:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\mySection}{+m !O{#1}}{
    \cleardoublepage
    \section{#1}
    \label{#2}
    }
```

(I used `!O` instead of `O` to require that the optional argument must appear immediately after the required argument so you can have a section beginning with a bracket). Then you could write:

```
\mySection{Introduction}[intro]

\ref{intro}
```

Comment: And, in the meantime, you lose all features of the original `\section` command. Just to provide something that has no advantage whatsoever.

Comment: Very weird because I tried exactly that approach but get different errors. Maybe it's because the `\newcommand` instead of `\NewDocumentCommand`. Could you present resources with the difference of these two methods of assigning and especially why it's better to use the latter? E: I cannot reproduce the error but it was a error with the labeling.

Comment: @egreg It's simple enough to modify the declaration to have an arg spec of `+O{#2}  +m !O{#2}` to reclaim `\section`'s optional argument. `\section*` (which is a dubious variant) doesn't make sense in the context of this task. But yes, I wouldn't do it this way either.